# Adding AwesomeMenu in appdelegate

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to add awesomeMenu in my project but there is a problem in awesomemenu's appdelegate file in
Appdelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,AwesomeMenuDelegate> 
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window; 
@end
```

is there

and in our normal appdelegate.h file there is

```
@interface AppController : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, CCDirectorDelegate>
{
UIWindow *window_;
UINavigationController *navController_;
CCDirectorIOS   *director_;                         // weak ref
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
@property (readonly) UINavigationController *navController;
@property (readonly) CCDirectorIOS *director;

@end
```

now if i change CCdirectordelegate to AwesomeMenudelegate there will be error 
how to implement it?
Is there possibility to use it in helloworld layer
or we have to operate awesomemenu from appdelegate?

or is there possible to implement two interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compine AwesomeMenu with Cocos2d project you don't have to remove from your AppDelegate.h the CCDirectorDelegate.   This is what I have done and works:

1. create a new project based on default cocos2d template
   (if you want to be up to date, create a local copy of AwesomeMenu's github project)
2. add to the project 2 subdirectory of AwesomeMenu: AwesomeMenu/AwesomeMenu (4 files inside) and Images
3. only modify 2 files: HelloWorldLayer.h and HelloWorldLayer.m

**HelloWorldLayer.h** (added an import AwesomeMenu.h, and a AwesomeMenuDelegate)

```
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
#import "AwesomeMenu.h"

// When you import this file, you import all the cocos2d classes
#import "cocos2d.h"

// HelloWorldLayer
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer <GKAchievementViewControllerDelegate,
                                      GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate,
                                      AwesomeMenuDelegate>
{
}
```

**HelloWorldLayer.m** (modify only the init method by deleting GameCenter code and add example AwesomeMenu menu with slight modification):

```
-(id) init
{
  // always call "super" init
  // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super's" return value
  if( (self=[super init]) ) {
    // ask director for the window size
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];




    UIImage *storyMenuItemImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-menuitem.png"];
    UIImage *storyMenuItemImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-menuitem-highlighted.png"];

    UIImage *starImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-star.png"];

    AwesomeMenuItem *starMenuItem1 = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] initWithImage:storyMenuItemImage
                                                           highlightedImage:storyMenuItemImagePressed
                                                               ContentImage:starImage
                                                    highlightedContentImage:nil];
    AwesomeMenuItem *starMenuItem2 = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] initWithImage:storyMenuItemImage
                                                           highlightedImage:storyMenuItemImagePressed
                                                               ContentImage:starImage
                                                    highlightedContentImage:nil];
    AwesomeMenuItem *starMenuItem3 = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] initWithImage:storyMenuItemImage
                                                           highlightedImage:storyMenuItemImagePressed
                                                               ContentImage:starImage
                                                    highlightedContentImage:nil];
    AwesomeMenuItem *starMenuItem4 = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] initWithImage:storyMenuItemImage
                                                           highlightedImage:storyMenuItemImagePressed
                                                               ContentImage:starImage
                                                    highlightedContentImage:nil];
    AwesomeMenuItem *starMenuItem5 = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] initWithImage:storyMenuItemImage
                                                           highlightedImage:storyMenuItemImagePressed
                                                               ContentImage:starImage
                                                    highlightedContentImage:nil];
    AwesomeMenuItem *starMenuItem6 = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] initWithImage:storyMenuItemImage
                                                           highlightedImage:storyMenuItemImagePressed
                                                               ContentImage:starImage
                                                    highlightedContentImage:nil];
    AwesomeMenuItem *starMenuItem7 = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] initWithImage:storyMenuItemImage
                                                           highlightedImage:storyMenuItemImagePressed
                                                               ContentImage:starImage
                                                    highlightedContentImage:nil];
    AwesomeMenuItem *starMenuItem8 = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] initWithImage:storyMenuItemImage
                                                           highlightedImage:storyMenuItemImagePressed
                                                               ContentImage:starImage
                                                    highlightedContentImage:nil];
    AwesomeMenuItem *starMenuItem9 = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] initWithImage:storyMenuItemImage
                                                           highlightedImage:storyMenuItemImagePressed
                                                               ContentImage:starImage
                                                    highlightedContentImage:nil];

    NSArray *menus = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:starMenuItem1, starMenuItem2, starMenuItem3, starMenuItem4, starMenuItem5, starMenuItem6, starMenuItem7,starMenuItem8,starMenuItem9, nil];

    AwesomeMenu *menu = [[AwesomeMenu alloc] initWithFrame:[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] window].bounds menus:menus];   // PLS NOTE: referencing window

    // customize menu
    /*
     menu.rotateAngle = M_PI/3;
     menu.menuWholeAngle = M_PI;
     menu.timeOffset = 0.2f;
     menu.farRadius = 180.0f;
     menu.endRadius = 100.0f;
     menu.nearRadius = 50.0f;
     */

    //menu.startPoint = CGPointMake(120.0, 240.0);

    menu.delegate = self;

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:menu]; // PLS NOTE: referencing view

}
return self;
```

}

Hope you can manage in your own app!